# nodes and udp implementation in NS-3

Tags: c++, ns-3

3 and I'm currently trying to alter some of the codes in the examples section without any success.

```
#include "ns3/core-module.h"
#include "ns3/network-module.h"
#include "ns3/internet-module.h"
#include "ns3/point-to-point-module.h"
#include "ns3/applications-module.h"

using namespace ns3;

NS_LOG_COMPONENT_DEFINE("FirstScriptExample");

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    Time::SetResolution(Time::NS);
    LogComponentEnable("UdpEchoClientApplication", LOG_LEVEL_INFO);
    LogComponentEnable("UdpEchoServerApplication", LOG_LEVEL_INFO);

    NodeContainer nodes;
    nodes.Create(2);

    PointToPointHelper pointToPoint;
    pointToPoint.SetDeviceAttribute("DataRate", StringValue("5Mbps"));
    pointToPoint.SetChannelAttribute("Delay", StringValue("2ms"));

    NetDeviceContainer devices;
    devices = pointToPoint.Install(nodes);

    InternetStackHelper stack;
    stack.Install(nodes);

    Ipv4AddressHelper address;
    address.SetBase("10.1.1.0", "255.255.255.0");

    Ipv4InterfaceContainer interfaces = address.Assign(devices);

    UdpEchoServerHelper echoServer(9);

    ApplicationContainer serverApps = echoServer.Install(nodes.Get(1));
    serverApps.Start(Seconds(1.0));
    serverApps.Stop(Seconds(10.0));

    UdpEchoClientHelper echoClient(interfaces.GetAddress(1), 9);
    echoClient.SetAttribute("MaxPackets", UintegerValue(1));
    echoClient.SetAttribute("Interval", TimeValue(Seconds(1.0)));
    echoClient.SetAttribute("PacketSize", UintegerValue(1024));

    ApplicationContainer clientApps = echoClient.Install(nodes.Get(0));
    clientApps.Start(Seconds(2.0));
    clientApps.Stop(Seconds(10.0));

    Simulator::Run();
    Simulator::Destroy();
    return 0;
}
```

This is the first tutorial example and I'm trying to create 4 nodes so they could send some udp packets to one another.

Any advice?

Comment: Added proper indentation to the code snippet

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways to do it based on the network topology you want to work on. If you want to have four nodes sharing the same shared medium, you can simply do a `node.Create (4)` and install a `CsmaHelper` on your `NodeContainer`, you can checkout **/examples/tutorial/second.cc** for a simple implementation of this.

But if you want a dumbbell like topology with one leaf node on each side and one central channel, you will have to create three `NodeContainer` with PointToPointHelper installed on each of them.

```
NodeContainer leftLeaf, rightLeaf, central;
leftLeaf.Create(2); //creates two left side node
rightLeaf.Create(2); //creates two right side node
central.Add(leftLeaf.Get(1)); //add one node from left in central link
central.Add(rightLeaf.Get(1)); //add one node from right in central link
```

You will also have to set forwarding on for the central link nodes.

This is done because a point to point link must have exactly two end points. For such topology you can even use `PointToPointDumbbellHelper`, an implementation for which can be found in **src/traffic-control/examples/red-vs-ared.cc**

Comment: thank you!might i also ask another quastion?if I have 2 nodes and I connect them point2point,if I want to have a duplex link so the 2 nodes could communicate with eachother shall I add 2 ip addresses with internet stack helper?

Comment: No, you will have to give a single address subnet using Ipv4AddressHelper and assign this to the NetDeviceContainer you would have installed on your node.

Comment: oh ok! and then I would just need a TCP source and sink apps for both of the nodes...am I right?

Comment: yes, after setting up the internet stack, you just need to configure a source and sink app

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create 4 nodes, you can change the number in the code `nodes.Create(2)`. But you must link these nodes through `PointToPointHelper` or `CsmaHelper`. Then you must give every interface a IP address. Finally you need install UDP or TCP application that you can customize on the nodes.

Your problem is very simple. But I can't provide more details because of my poor English.

But I think you can see the ns3 [tutorial](https://www.nsnam.org/docs/release/3.25/tutorial/html/conceptual-overview.html), especially **A First ns-3 Script** part.